# Using GPG from another user (GNU/Linux)

Tags: linux, gnupg, sudo

I want to use gpg from another user *(user2)*, so that the primary user *(user1)* does not have access to the encrypted file, but only to the part the script will output.

Added a sudo rule for *user1* to run `/bin/gpg` as *user2*. When I try to execute `user1@host: sudo -u user2 gpg /home/user2/pass.gpg` an error `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` appears *(symmetric encryption)*.

I add the `--pinentry-mode loopback` parameter, the password is requested directly in the console *(without any "Enter password" or input field, just on a new line)* and decryption takes place.

From what I've read, using the `pinentry-mode loopback` option reduces security because the password is transferred without using gpg-agent, but directly with gpg. Did I get it right or is this parameter safe to use? Or is there another way to achieve your goal?

Comment: Instead of playing with *fake* user, you could play with `GNUPGHOME=$HOME/.alternate-gnupg gpg ...` to store *other pseudo user* profile under **your** private permissions.

Comment: @F.Hauri I'm sorry, but I don't quite get it. There is a `file.gpg` that should not be readable from *user1*. If I specify `.alternate-gnupg` from under *user2*, there is a `error with agent gpg` when I try to decrypt it. And if I decrypt from *user1* I have no permissions for `file.gpg`.